# Drawing TChart Legend outside of TChart

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'd like to draw TChart Legend outside of TChart, for example in TPanel. Is it possible? I use Delphi7, TeeChart8.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  The easiest way would be to make two TCharts that shared series data (Using `Series[i].AssignValues`).  Format one chart to show only the chart.  Format the other to show only the legend -- simply make all other chart objects not visible and choose a custom location for the legend.  Otherwise, the legend and the chart are somewhat tightly coupled.  Designing something from a `TeeCustomPanel` would be a fair amount of work.

Comment: Thank you, very good idea (with second TChart), I made it and it's OK.

Comment: @J... you should make that an answer. It's a very nice workaround.